# What are the differences between zero-energy Majorana modes and Majorana edge modes?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, majorana-fermions

1. if i assume that i have a 2d p+ip super conductor, donut like geometry, and anti-periodic boundary condutions for fermionic field, and no flux. i find majorana edge modes. but the excitation spectrum is **gapped**.
2. if i consider same system with flux through hole, i should now consider periodic b.c. and i get zero-energy (**no gap** )majorana edge modes each **localized** at 1 edge.

now the confusing part is do i have majorana modes that are localized at 1  edge in first case?

the systems, i mention, are discussed in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1293 at section 2.b.

Comment: I do not understand : it seems to me the question in the title is not related to your question in the text. The answer to the title question is : there is no difference between zero-energy Majorana modes in a gapped situation and edge state, since an isolated mode inside a gap can only form at the surface of the materials. The question in the text is about the change of boundary condition and the presence or absence of zero-energy mode, as far as I can see. To my understanding, an anti-periodic boundary condition is the same as putting half a flux quantum in a ring, isn't it ?

Comment: my question is when i have zero energy mode in half flux quantum case i have zero energy mode at edges which is isolated. but when i dont have flux (i.e. anti periodic bc) i dont have zero enegry modes. but there are edge majorana modes with energy. so is the latter isolated like the former?

Comment: You can always write everything in terms of Majorana modes if you like, what are interesting are the Majorana modes at zero-energy, since these ones have interesting properties for topological computation. I do not understand the problem with the flux, how is it that anti-periodic boundary condition can be realised without (eventually not mentioned or fictitious)  flux ?

Comment: that's exactly my point. you can write every thing in terms of majorana fermions the interesting thing is when you have isolated modes. which means you have 2 end majorana modes which makes 1 delocalized fermion.
so is this de localization only appears when these end modes have no energy?

Comment: about the flux case as far as i understand, when we don't have flux we need periodic bc, but in this case we have a exp(i*thetha) term in front of the pairing term in hamiltonian which makes pairing of two different angular momentum. to get rid of it we make gauge transformation exp(-i*thehta/2). which makes our new field has anti periodic bc.

Comment: The delocalisation appears each time the wave functions associated to each mode do not overlap, or when the overlap goes as $e^{l/L}$, with $l$ the distance between the two modes, and $L$ a characteristic length. Since one needs an energy gap $\Delta$ to get evanescent modes, the length $L$ is proportional to the inverse of the gap.